# Pushing changes to a specific remote branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have remote branches such as:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/development
  origin/deploy-prod
  origin/development
  origin/master
```

I checkout origin/master as

```
$ git checkout -b trq17 origin/master
$ git branch
  development
* trq17
```

Now I want to push changes in trq17 branch into remote origin/master. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to merge them first, then push the result to remote.  This reduces the likelihood that one is going to push broken code, or code that has conflicts.

```
 git checkout master
 git merge trq17
 git commit (if there was a merge commit or conflicts occurred)
 git push origin master
```